# How to get all the Accent Colors and Names in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal

In Windows 10, the accent colours have names (see screen shot). I have looked in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/style/color), and see the colour codes, but can't see any names.

Is there a way to reference these colours in XAML using their name?

I am trying to replace something like this with

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">#FF00CC6A</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

with

```
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Color x:Key="SystemAccentColor">TurfGreen</Color>
    </ResourceDictionary>
```

[image: Windows 10 Accent Colors]

Alternatively, does anyone have a full list of the names for these colors?
If so, I can just make a new resource dictionary with the values.

Comment: Why don't you get all the name using the same method(ToolTip from Accent Color)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use color name istead of Hexadecimal code in case the color name in Settings matches the color name in C#, but that might not be the case always. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but you can definitely read the names from the tooltips and then hardcode them into your app using a class which has a `Name` and a `Color` property.